# difference between hybris 5.5.1.1 vs 5.5.1.2?

Tags: e-commerce, sap-commerce-cloud

Can anyone tell me what are the new features added in hybris 5.5.1.2 release when compared to hybris 5.5.1.1 release in hybris?Any one throw some light on it...

Answer (score 0):

There are usually no features added in minor releases (anything from third qualifier on), usually those releases only contain critical security fixes and blocker/critical issues.

You can find more details for 5.5.1.2 here (scroll down a bit and you'll see it):
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/downloads/Archived+5.5.1+Release

If you have a hybris jira account you can look at the patch ticket: https://jira.hybris.com/browse/PATCH-2070

The issues mentioned in there are:

ECP-388: Running Initialization or Update from hAC causing SQLException on weblogic

ECP-537: Cronjobs in cluster: allow to set nodeGroup/nodeID without recreating the trigger

ECP-540: synchronousOM extension dump in 5.5.1.1 during build process

ECP-552: Datahub 5.5.1 -mysql 5.6 (linux) Could not load extension for raw type RawHybrisCustomer

Hope that helps!